# Specs2 - How to define complex objects for Given/When/Then steps

Tags: scala, bdd, agile, specs2

Specs2's documentation and samples show some codes about the use of Given/Then/When style in an acceptance test.

Here one of them:

```
"A given-when-then example for the addition"                   ^
    "Given the following number: ${1}"                         ^ number1 ^
    "And a second number: ${2}"                                ^ number2 ^
    "And a third number: ${3}"                                 ^ number3

  val number1: Given[Int]               = (_:String).toInt
  val number2: When[Int, (Int, Int)]    = (n1: Int) => (s: String) => (n1, s.toInt)
  val number3: When[Seq[Int], Seq[Int]] = (numbers: Seq[Int]) => (s: String) => numbers :+ s.toInt
```

However, it only deal with some primitive objects as `Int` here (normal since it's a sample).

But how to deal with complex objects? Using `Datatables`?

Ideal would be to define, within some file of "fixtures", datatables (or similar things) defining complex objects.

*External datatable defining the `User` "Mik"*

```
"name" |   "job"    | "e-mail"
"mik"  | "engineer" | "mik@mik.com"
```

I would like to create a Given statement like this one:

```
"Given the following user: ${Mik}"       ^ retrieve_user_from_database ^

val user: Given[User]               = .....Some ideal codes here to map Mik's values to User model.
```

What is a good practice and what does Specs2 currently provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve a user from an existing database, you can do the following:

```
"Given the following user: ${Mik}" ^ user ^

val user: Given[User] = (name: String) => database.getUserByName(name)
```

Now you might want to populate your database with users before doing that. One possibility is indeed to use Datatables:

```
def populateDatabase = 
  "name" ||   "job"    | "e-mail"        |
  "mik"  !! "engineer" ! "mik@mik.com"   |
  "eric" !! "engineer" ! "eric@eric.com" | { (name, job, email) => 
    database.saveUser(User(name, job, email)) must not(throwAn[Exception])
  }
```

and put this in a `Step` before your G/W/T group:

```
Step(populateDatabase) ^
"Given the following user: ${Mik}"  ^ user ^
"This user should be an ${engineer} ^ jobOk ^
                                      end

val user: Given[User] = (name: String) => database.getUserByName(name)
val jobOk: Then[User] = (user: User) => (job: String) => user.job must_== job
```

Comment: Great! :) I will create a specific trait call 'fixtures' for instance, defining all concerned domain objects for my specs. Thanks Eric !

Comment: I created a very similar example to yours. First, I noticed the last operator of your datatable: `|` (well existing in specs2 code) instead of `|>` as shown in the documentation. With your version, the database insertion doesn't occur, despite of the presence of the `Step(populateDatabase)`. I tried with the other operator: `|>`, and the insertion, this time, occurs. Howevere, I got this exception: `"org.specs2.execute.Error$ThrowableException: DecoratedResultException: null`. I trust your code :) but what may be the reason explaining why insertion not occurs using "|" ?

Comment: That's my mistake, the table only executes with '>'. The exception is likely to be caused by a val instead of lazy val in your trait.

Comment: I already wondered about initialization of val with trait (tricky in scala when one comes from Java) but it isn't the cause. It's the association with `ThrownExpectations` trait that makes my spec fail with the error above. When I omit it, that works. I inspect the source code in order to understand why :)  Thanks again !! :) For information, my spec's declaration is: `class IntegrationSpec extends Specification with WebDriverInit with DataSourceInit with Fixtures with ThrownExpectations`. `Fixtures` itself is: `trait Fixtures extends Specification with DataTables with DataSourceInit`.